Converting Numeric Values to Categorial (strings ) in a data frame column
trying to change frequency table headings which are  values in a column (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) within a dataframe
1    2    3    4    5    6   77 
2780  396  579  186 1004  527    2  261
to
Married  NeverMarried , Divorced, etc..
2780      396            579
here is my code
bltest_m <- bltest %>%
  mutate(DMDMARTL = cut( breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), labels = c("Married", "NeverMarried", "Divoced","Livingpartner", "Widowed", "Refused")))

###got this
rror in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `DMDMARTL = cut(...)`.
Caused by error in `cut.default()`:
! argument "x" is missing, with no default
Backtrace:
  1. bltest %>% ...
 10. base::cut.default(...)


Your variable is missing as the first argument in cut
